# Update Suite Bar links after Server Host Name Change using Rename-SPServer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, suitebar, suite-links

I have changed a Sharepoint 2016 server hostname using `Rename-SPServer` PowerShell cmdlet. I also changed the Alternate Access Mapping Urls for all the sites. Everything seems to be working fine accept for the Suite Bar links. They are still pointing to the old hostname based urls. Can anyone suggest how to fix them?

I have restarted the server to see if the problem goes away. But it is not working.

### Update

Just realized every link in the User profile page(About Me) is also pointing to the old hostname. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running the below PowerShell that will update the SuiteBar in SharePoint 2016 . Below code updates Logo Image,Title and the Link. If you want to update only the link, you just have to update the **SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl** property.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$WebApp= Get-SPWebApplication "http://intranet.crescent.com"
$WebApp.SuiteNavBrandingText = "Crescent Portal"

#Blank image from Layouts folder
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoUrl = "/_layouts/images/dot_ruleper.gif"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoTitle = "Crescent Logo"
$webapp.SuiteNavBrandingLogoNavigationUrl = "http://portal.crescent.com"
$webapp.Update()
```

[image]

[More Reference Link 1](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/10/customize-suitebar-text-link-in-sharepoint-2016-using-powershell.html)

[More Reference Link 2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-change-suit-bar-in-sharepoint-2016/)

In case **any other links in the suite bar** is not updated, Can you please navigate to the Central Administration, User Profile Service Application -> Under My Site Settings -> Setup My Sites. See if the Site URL is correct. If not, Update the changes

Comment: but all the links in suitbar seems to be wrong. e.g. "Sites", "About me" etc. how to fix them?

Comment: Can you please navigate to the Central Administration, User Profile Service Application -> Under My Site Settings -> Setup My Sites. See if the Site URL is correct. If not, Update the changes

Comment: you are right. it was not updated there. thank you. you really saved me :)

Comment: Awesome ! I will update the main answer so that it helps others as well !